# suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm using a web service but the following error prevents me from getting it to work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Marnik\Documents\GitHub\prjct\CompareSiteCrawler\src\Crawlers\Belboon.py", line 9, in <module>
client = suds.client.Client(url,plugins=[ImportDoctor(imp)])
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\python-suds-0.4\suds\client.py", line 119, in __init__
sd = ServiceDefinition(self.wsdl, s)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\python-suds-0.4\suds\servicedefinition.py", line 57, in __init__
self.addports()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\python-suds-0.4\suds\servicedefinition.py", line 85, in    addports
method = (m.name, binding.param_defs(m))
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\python-suds-0.4\suds\bindings\rpc.py", line 39, in param_defs
return self.bodypart_types(method)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\python-suds-0.4\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 441, in   bodypart_types
raise TypeNotFound(query.ref)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'
```

Now I've searched for solutions and almost all of the found solutions is the following, or one very similar:

```
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', location='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('http://ws.client.com/Members.asmx')
client = Client(url,plugins=[ImportDoctor(imp)]
```

This doesn't work for me though, even after replacing the part after the imp.filter.add with the `targetNameSpace` of the WSDL file. I'm not very familiar with WSDL but I spitted trough the xml file and encountered the following:

```
<definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="urn:SmartFeedServices" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="SmartFeedServices" targetNamespace="urn:SmartFeedServices">
    <types xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    <!--  Messages  -->
    <!--  Input parameters for method login  -->
```

Looking at other WSDL  files I noticed two things: The `targetNameSpace` at this particular XML file is not an url, where all other WSDL files I looked at had an url as `targetNameSpace`.

Second, The type element is empty. Other WSDL files have other elements here instead, like the `targetNameSpace`.

Could one of the two (or both) be the problem?

Comment: I have a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721035/type-not-found-wsdl-python-suds-client-suds-typenotfound

Comment: I used soappy and it worked if it helps (although not a solution)

Comment: Tried that already, didn't work for me